# Upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 now wireless does not work.

Tags: wireless

When I try to install addition driver that is required this error message comes up:-

"Sorry, the installation of this driver failed.

Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log"

Comment: What additional driver?  Can you install that driver when connected to the internet over a wired connection?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Please name your wifi card, and provide the log contents.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove and reinstall the Broadcom driver.
The easiest way to do that is:

//remove the old driver

```
$ sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

//install the new one

```
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

// reboot your system

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Why do you think it's a Broadcom driver?